# Own sync adapter for Android?

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

The press release of Android 2.0 states that the new release supports sync adapters so that emails and calendars cannot only be synced with gmail and exchange. However, there is no information available online how to write such a sync adapter. Has anyone tried it and some example code available?

Answer (score 26):

These two articles by Sam Steele (January 23rd, 2010) are about the implementation of the [last.fm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fm.last.android) sync adapter. Do not miss the second part and the opensource projects that are mentioned at the end of the articles.

- http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/
- http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/
- https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-android/
- https://github.com/c99koder/AndroidSyncProviderDemo

Answer (score 13):

This article, http://ericmiles.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/connecting-the-dots-with-android-syncadapter/, is a great, albeit brief overview of creating a sync adapter and getting it to play nice within the Android framework.

Answer (score 4):

Simple basic explanation by Adam Pullen (last updated May 13, 2011). The article consists of two parts and contains the *ShowMyAccountAuthenticator* example project.

- http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step
- http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-1
- http://www.finalconcept.com.au/uploads/files/showmyaccountauthenticator.zip

Answer (score 2):

I'm still learning myself, but this thread should help you understand a little bit.

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg64769.html

Answer (score 1):

The [article of Kyle Miller](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/breaking-down-googles-samplesyncadapter/1037) (March 10, 2012) summarizes how to get started with the SampleSyncAdapter project contained in the SDK samples. He describes how you can add an account for the app in the system settings of your phone. Basically, he explains how the classes `AuthenticationService`, `Authenticator` and `AuthenticatorActivity` are used to handle the server authentication using a token. At the end of the article are some words about `authenticator.xml`, `syncadapter.xml` and `contacts.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I found

[Implements a SyncAdapter for Contacts](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#kXGhTi8cgHk/src/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsSyncAdapter.java&q=Android%20SyncAdapter&sa=N&cd=4&ct=rc)

Not sure if this is what we need to help us roll our own contacts sync service though.

Answer (score 0):

I found this browsable source code of the android exchange sync adapter from the android sources:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r2.1/com/android/exchange/adapter/ContactsSyncAdapter.java?av=f

These where not included, when I manually checked out the android sources at http://source.android.com . Maybe someone can find the appropriate sources of the original google calendar/contact sync adapter? (not just the MS exchange ones)

Here is a german student research paper I found through google:

ftp://ftp.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pub/library/medoc.ustuttgart_fi/STUD-2348/STUD-2348.pdf