# How to code a "sync now" operation on Android?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have a sync adapter for my DB and at certain points in the application usage, it needs to sync the DB now.  I would like to trigger the sync adapter as if its sync-time popped and then re-establish the sync time (i.e., 4 hours from this 'sync now" event).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think (not tested) a better solution is already defined in the ContentResolver.

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(account, authority, extras);
```

so one might do the following:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
Account account =  null;
am.getAccountsByType(mytype);
for(Account a : accounts) {
    if (am.getUserData(account, key)) {
        account = a;
        break;
    }
}
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString(EXTRA_mystuff, myvalue);
ContentResolver.requestSync(account, authority, extras)
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is "authority"? Documentation says it is "the provider whose behavior is being controlled"....what does this mean?

Comment: @user1204089 it is the `contentAuthority` that you specified in the resource of your `<sync-adapter>`. Also, you can just supply `null` for `account` for all of them