# What are Android SyncAdapter contentAuthority and accountType?

Tags: android, xml, android-syncadapter, reverse-dns

I'm creating a custom Android SyncAdapter and hit a snag following the SDK example "SampleSyncAdapter". - I'm creating my equivalent of the `xml/syncadapter.xml`. Here's the parts I'm confused about:

```
android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
android:accountType="com.example.android.samplesync"
```

The [documentation of AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html) states:

> The `android:contentAuthority` and `android:accountType` attributes
>   indicate which content authority and for which account types this sync
>   adapter serves.

The documentation is circular in that it says nothing the name doesn't already tell you. I get the impression that both will start with my company's name `com.acme.` but from there I have no clue. I suspect the strings can be anything, as long as they are globally unique so as not to conflict with any other apps that could be on the same device. I assume this means I will need to use these exact strings elsewhere in my code. However, I'd like to know, where I will need these strings?! I tried to grep for `com.android.contacts` and the previously mentioned file is the only place it is used, I can find. So it is impossible to tell how the `contentAuthority` is used by looking at the example.
If so, can I put them both in a string resource and reference them in by resource ID where needed? Exactly what are these attributes and how are they used? Is there any better way to figure out what values I should choose for my own application for these and other fields?

Comment: Not a duplicate but related question [Should I use android AccountManager?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8614699/94363)

Answer (score 5):

To understand what the authority is you need to see the [documentation of ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html):

It states: "it identifies the content provider. For third-party applications, this should be a fully-qualified class name (reduced to lowercase) to ensure uniqueness. The authority is declared in the  element's authorities attribute"

The account type is an identificator of your Authenticator that will be used for example by the clients of the *AccountManager* to call `getAccountsByType(String)`.

For the *SampleSyncAdapter*:

```
android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
android:accountType="com.example.android.samplesync"
```

android:accountType is the same as that one defined by the authenticator.

So the content-Authority specifies which content provider will be synchronized locally and the accountType specifies which authenticator will be used to access the data remotely.
The accountType is also used to obtain the sync adapter's specific content-uri.

For example when you want to start a sync you need to call *requestSync* like this:

```
final Account account = new Account(accountName, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
ContentResolver.requestSync(account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, new Bundle());
```

At the same time to build the content-uri for your sync adapter you can use something like:

```
Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName).appendQueryParameter(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, SyncAdapter.ACCOUNT_TYPE).build();
```

Have a look to [android-sync-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994843/android-sync-adapter)

---

Meanwhile, the previously mentioned ContentProvider documentation has been revised. The [latest version](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI) states:

> **Designing an authority**
>
> A provider usually has a single authority, which serves as its
>   Android-internal name. To avoid conflicts with other providers, you
>   should use Internet domain ownership (in reverse) as the basis of your
>   provider authority. Because this recommendation is also true for
>   Android package names, you can define your provider authority as an
>   extension of the name of the package containing the provider. For
>   example, if your Android package name is `com.example.<appname>`, you
>   should give your provider the authority
>   `com.example.<appname>.provider`.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Here's why.  Using a fully qualified class name that is lowercase contradicts the Notepad example AUTHORITY ("com.google.provider.NotePad").  The contentAuthority is for a SyncAdapter.  The fully qualified name would not contain "provider" nor a capitalized NotePad.

Comment: "For third-party applications...". It means that it is not strange that the NotePad uses capital letters.

Comment: and please have a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649808/syncadapter-without-a-contentprovider

Comment: As I understand it, the Notepad example was written by Google to show Third party developers an example of how to write an app.  Are you saying it's written by Google so they showing third party developers an app as if they worked at Google?   
 
What about the "provider" in the example?  The simpler reason for the inconsistency is that the link you describe is talking about a Provider and not a SyncAdapter.  From your quote: "The authority is declared in the element's authorities attribute".  Note they describe "authorities" and not "contentAuthority", which is what my question is about.

Comment: herschel is right. the accountAuthority references which contentProvider is responsible for this synadapter (for example: contacts). The accountType identifies your generated account (for example for your app. Facebook, twitter, last.fm all create such accounts to manager their "own" data). Also the name "provider" would be ok, as its part of the classname.

Comment: Sorry for insisting but what about this comment (that you can find here http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html): 

The sync adapter (essential to the synchronization service) declares the account type and ContentProvider authority to the sync manager.

Answer (score 0):

The android:contentAuthority attribute in your SyncAdapter meta data file syncadapter.xml should match the android:authorities attribute for your provider declaration in your Manifest. Make this value your app's package name with the string ".provider" appended to it. This is from Android's developer site http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters

So in your Manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="com.example.android.datasync.provider.StubProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.android.datasync.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:syncable="true"/>
```

And in your syncadapter.xml

```
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="com.example.android.datasync.provider"
    android:accountType="com.android.example.datasync"
    android:userVisible="false"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```