# Running the Android example SampleSyncAdapter

Tags: android

I installed the example SampleSyncAdapter from the sdk into eclipse--it runs in the emulator--e.g, if i go to Settings>>Account & Sync, I do see the SamplesyncAdapter Account--but i can't log in when i select it--the Google documentation is next to useless in terms of orienting developers--what should I enter to log in? How do I run the application--I want to run it in debug to walk thru the code.

UPDATE: i found answer--if anyone is having same issue:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ac875a97679122f0

Refer to the reply by Megha in the above thread--also, refer to the class NetworkUtilities if you are trying to understand how the external server is contacted for the update--in my case I will alter this class to point to a local tomcat/servlet to experiment.

It sure is hard to understand why the Google Developer Reference site does not contain the information in the above thread--which was supplied by a google employee over a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

yes, that link is interesting, there you will find information about the serverside, but here you have other interesting links bout it:

- this is the documentation in developer.android.com :
  http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html
- here's an article where you will also find information about the 
  components of the Android application:
  http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/breaking-down-googles-samplesyncadapter/1037
- and here's other interesting article here on StackOverflow :
  [How do I use the Android SyncAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994843/how-do-i-use-the-android-syncadapter)