# Android Sync Adapter Resources

Tags: android, synchronization, client-server

Does anyone know of any books or online resources (except the dev docs) that cover the [Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters) and its usage?  Struggling to find any good material myself.

Or.. does anyone know of any alternative libraries for conducting remote sync services?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't done this on my own yet. But here are 2 links about this: [a guide with code](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/) (not accepted but might help) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859241/own-sync-adapter-for-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Own sync adapter for Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859241/own-sync-adapter-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't any good resources at this point. If I had to guess at why, it is because the actual implementation of a sync is going to be very specific to each app. I am writing one right now, and it is very trial and error.

We could definitely benefit from a good tutorial on some of the more well known api's out there (an implementation of a twitter account sync for example). Maybe they will finally release the official twitter app code like they have been promising.