# Sync Android phone with a third-party server

Tags: android

Do you know if the Android SDK provides some classes, interfaces or methods to help developers to create a mechanism in order to synchronize application data between the phone and a third-party server ?
Or should we build this mechanism from scratch ?

I've heard about C2DM for Push notification but it is available only from Android 2.2 and my application must support Android 2.1.

Comment: Is your question about Syncing data or about Push notification?

Answer (score 4):

Android does synchronization between data stored locally in a content provider and a remote service by means of a `SyncAdapter`.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) you have a full example and [some](http://ericmiles.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/connecting-the-dots-with-android-syncadapter/) [docs](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/).

Answer (score 0):

It s been a while but I couldnT find a lot of info on *Sync* management in Android nowadays either. I wanted to add another link. :

- http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/ . It s also quite old actually(from *January, 2010*)
- Then there is another SO post : [Android Sync Adapter Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780369/android-sync-adapter-resources)