# How to share and sync android sqlite database across devices when they are updated?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am a novice android app developer. Currently I am developing an app which has a sqlite database. Users store some data in that database. Now I want to add an online synchronization / data sharing feature in my app - If a user update his/her device's database( that means store / delete data ) all other users of that app will get that update through internet( I mean their sqlite database will updated accordingly ). How can I do that?

I have searched about this and found about Sync Adapter. But I am still puzzled sync adapter would solve my problem or not. And how can I share sqlite database across devices.

Please give a newbie friendly answer. Any easy Tutorial / Documentation will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases are created on each device - specific to the storage system, etc.

To "share a database" you need to share the data. Essentially, it is an export/import process. So the data will export from one device and import into another.

You can do this by storing the data in JSON or CSV format. The export creates a file (or is done in-memory) then needs to be sent view the network (probably HTTP) to a server. From there another device can download and import it into the database.

The import process must account for possible data conflicts (duplicates, etc.) and possible different database versions/structures. This can get very complicated, very quickly. Develop as much as you can before release - otherwise you will have all kinds of synchronization issues.

`SyncAdapter` can simplify some of this process for you. It also may not do waht you need or expect. Here's more info on that:

[Own sync adapter for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859241/own-sync-adapter-for-android)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no "easy" solution to the problem of syncing data between server & devices. As you rightly said, `SyncAdapter` & `ContentProvider` are the way to go. These are indeed quite difficult to use & implement for novice developers.

An alternative way is provided:

**1.** Set a boolean flag to `true` whenever a user changes the data on their device (i.e. whenever a new entry is made in the DB).

**2.** Check if internet is ON. If it is, update this data on the server with the web service. Set the flag to `false`.

**3.** If internet is not available, let the flag remain `true`.

**4.** Create a `BroadcastReceiver` that gets activated whenever there is a change in network status (i.e. internet is switched ON or OFF). If internet is available and the flag is `true`, call the web service to update the data on the server. Set the flag to `false`.

**5.** The same `BroadcastReceiver` has another function: if internet is available, call another web service to get new data from the server. This should happen every time internet is available.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Actually when you answered my question I had no Idea about webservice. So it was difficult for me to judge, your post answers my question or not! :) . As I had no knowledge about web services I tried alternative methods like DropBoxSync but failed. Finally I had tried to sync the sqlite DB with a remote mySQL DB hosted on a server and Succeeded!

BTW what do you mean by webservice? syncing with remote DB I mentioned?

Comment: @AshfaqurRahman: sorry for late reply ... by web service, I mean the network call to a server-side URL from your mobile app that fetches data stored in a server-side database. Good to hear you succeeded :) However, I was the first to reply to your question. I think its only fair that you mark my answer as correct. Thanks :)